# Composition vs Generics

Tags: typescript, generics, composition

Assume I have an abstract class A and a three concrete classes that inherit from it, A1, A2 and A3. There is also a different hierarchy tree, with an abstract class B and a three concrete classes  B1, B2 and B3. Each concrete class A needs to hold a list of objects of a respectively B class. That means, A1 holds a list of B1. What would be a better solution:

1. Make A a generic class and make it to hold a generic list of T which extends B such as:

   ```
   abstract class A<T extends B> {
       protected arr: Array<T extends B>
   }
   ```

   This way, I should declare each A class as following:

   ```
      class A1 extends A<B1>
   ```
2. Use composition as follows:

   ```
   class A1 extends A {
       private arr: Array<B1>
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer generics if I have lots of similar code in different classes. So if your classes `A1, A2, A3` are similar in functionality and just differ in the `type of B object` then go with generics.  Other than this there is no strong reason I could think of for using generics. If the above reason doesn't hold go with `composition`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer second one!
Generic classes are used when you have a couple of methods and functionalities that should be applied to objects independent from their type.
other wise it's not a good design to declare a class as generic only for solve a composition problem!